# how to detect with jQuery if click is first or second click?

Tags: jquery

I am using fancybox and for some reason it only activates on the second click. I don't know whats up with it but I thought a simple fix would be that when something is clicked if it is the first time it has been clicked then fire the click event again. Does anyone know how I would know whether something has been clicked before or not?

Thanks

Comment: Rather investigate why nothing happens on the first click...

Comment: This could be achieved pretty easily.  But I don't understand the question really.  Have you got an example of the code?

Answer (score -2):

never mind i did it in the end. I added a class when it was clicked the first time so if it doesnt have a class add one and then fire the event again. Like so:

```
$('a.lifestyle').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')==false) {
        $(this).fancybox();
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $(this).click();
    } else {
        $(this).fancybox();
    }
});
```